# Is there a general equation which calculates the temperature which shifts the equilibrium mostly to the right which applies to most reactions?

Tags: thermodynamics

#### Say I have the following simple reaction

$
  \ce{HCl(aq) + NaOH(aq) \rightarrow NaCl(aq) + H2O(l)}
$

Does there exist a calculation which gives the ideal temperature for this reaction to occur at?

#### Background

I used this example as it was the easiest one I could think of from the top of my head but I mean this generally.

I tried looking this up but could only find calculations to do with how much heat is released.

#### Edit

Ideal meaning the point in temperature where the reaction will give the greatest yield of products. Kind of reminds me of enzymes the optimum temperature.

Like one of the commentators mentioned the haber process, **the temperature at which the equilibrium shifts mostly to the right**, or the minimum temperature required for the reaction to get going.

#### Actual question

Is there an equation which calculates the optimum/shifts equilibrium mostly to the right temperature or is it just empirical? I mean a general equation which might apply to most reactions, if there is such a thing?

Apologies for being vague.

Comment: My cat would sleep on just about any level surface in the house. Floors, windowsills, armchairs, tabletops, he doesn't seem to care. What is the ideal surface for a cat to sleep on? Same thing with your reaction.

Comment: How is 'ideal' defined?

Comment: You might want to consider using a different reaction that actually can have an optimized temperature; for example, the Haber–Bosch process (production of ammonia). Since the reaction is exothermic, the equilibrium of the reaction shifts at low temperatures to the side of the ammonia; however, high temperatures are required for an appropriate reaction rate. Therefore, there is an optimized temperature somewhere in between that leads to the maximum production rate.

Comment: Ideal for *what*? Fastest reaction? Most complete reaction? What about the pressure? Etc. And why do you think such an "ideal" condition exists?

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by “ideal” in this scenario. “Ideal” implies a value judgement, when here we need a measurable quantity to compare against

Comment: see edit please guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime when asking for ideal, optimal or the best, the one who asks must provide criteria, how the ideality, optimality or being the best is evaluated, as it is highly subjective criteria.

In reaction context, one of possible criteria is the maximal reaction quotient achieved at given reaction conditions, together with minimal expenses. This makes sense for slow enough reactions, what is not the case of  strong acid + base neutralisation.

The typical textbook case for optimization is catalyzed Haber-Bosch synthesis of ammonia:

$$\ce{3 H2(g) + N2(g) <=> 2 NH3(g)}$$

There are 4 major factors:

1. Increased temperature speeds up the reaction.
2. Increased pressure shifts equilibrium in favour of the product.
3. Increased temperature shifts the equilibrium constant in favour of the reactants.
4. Increased cost for higher pressure and temperature.

The reaction is performed as gases pass the solid state catalyst, ammonia is separated and remaining reactants are by loopback returned to react.

The pressure is kept as high as technologically reasonable. But there are higher time and operational expenses (device cost, energy spent) for higher pressure.

The major parameter to optimize is temperature:

- If too low, reaction is limited kinetically, only small fraction would react, in spite of the equilibrium position.
- If too high, reactants react fast, but just small fraction due low equilibrium constant value. And there is higher energy cost.

From evaluation of the reaction kinetics and thermodynamics, technological and cost aspects, the optimal pressure and temperature is determined.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should’ve used an equilibrium reaction… So this is looked at for each chemical equation on a case by case basis. For your example can the optimum or temperature and pressure at which the highest and fastest yield of products occurs be determined by an equation? or as an example are you just looking at the moles on the left vs right?

Comment: There is multiple empirical aspects.

Comment: I see, that’s all I needed to know, thank you.